# How to remove "get info" sidebar in a finder window?

Tags: finder, mojave

When I open a finder window I have this large side bar on the right hand site that provides some outline file info, size, modified date etc.

How can remove this sidebar?

My mac is running OSX 10.14.x (latest updates installed.)

[image: screenshot from Finder showing the sidebar]

Comment: Why the downvote, it might be a simple question, but a question none the less.. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View Menu > Hide Preview  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>P</kbd>